# Wordpress shortcode duplicates posts when called twice

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've build a shortcode that should show me the latest post in a specific category, here is the code

```
function latest_post($atts = '') {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'cat' => '',
    ), $atts );
    $args = array(
       'posts_per_page' => 1,
       'cat' => $atts['cat']
    );

    $content = "";
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach($posts as $post):
       $content = $content."<h2>". apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title) ."</h2>";
       $content = $content."<img src='".get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full')."' />";
       $content = $content."<p class='post-content-custom'>". apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ) ."</p>";
    endforeach;

    return $content;
}

add_shortcode('latest_post', 'latest_post');
```

Now the problem is that I need to call this plugin twice or more in the same page but I need it to show me the next post if the latest post is already showed on the page by the same shortcode.

For example I need:

`[latest_post cat="cars"]` ``` [latest_post cat="books"]``[latest_post cat="cars"] ```

Now the second time I call `[latest_post cat="cars"]` it should show me the `latest post - 1` because the latest post is already called by the first shortcode.

Comment: That's not how shortcodes work -- they break out of the content. You should update your shortcode to accept a number of posts to show, instead of calling the same one twice and expecting it to know there's an offset expected.

Comment: @BenM That's how it should work for me, as the page should be built with multiple latest posts from multiple categories and they should be mixed by hand

Comment: That's as may be, but there's no way to achieve that without passing through a second argument. For example: `[latest_post cat="book" count="2"]` replaces `[latest_post cat="books"][latest_post cat="cars"]`.

Comment: May be worth a call to `wp_reset_postdata()`! https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata